# How to stop the execution of an imported python script without exiting the python altogether?

Tags: python

In the example below, when I run `y_file.py`, I need `5` printed and `Hello` not printed.
How to stop the execution of an imported python script `x_file.py` without exiting the python altogether? `sys.exit()` seems to exit python altogether.

`x_file.py`

```
import sys
x = 5
if __name__ != '__main__':
  pass
  # stop executing x.py, but do not exit python
  # sys.exit() # this line exits python
print("Hello")
```

`y_file.py`

```
import x_file
print(x_file.x)
```

Comment: Why don't you place the `print("Hello")` inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` ?

Comment: @jvx8ss because IRL there is much more than one line, and I don't want to have a diff on so many lines. Also, academic interest :)

Answer (score 0):

As [jvx8ss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107859/jvx8ss) suggested, you can fix this by putting the print inside a `if __name__ == "__main__":` conditional. Note the equality "==" instead of inequality "!=".
Final code:

```
import sys
x = 5
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stop executing x.py, but do not exit python
    # sys.exit() # this line exits python
    print("Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am well aware of this option, but I wanted to solve the problem differently!

Comment: Could you describe in your question why this is not a good answer? With the example you've provided it's not clear what you care about and what you don't

Answer (score 0):

You should place your code you don't want to run in the import inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` however, there is an **extremely bad** way to do what you want that I can think of using `Exception`

```py
# x_file.py
x = 5

if __name__ != '__main__':
  raise Exception(x)

print("Hello")
```

```py
# y_file.py
try:
    import x_file
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args[0])
```